# Add numbers from string values, excel

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have a table which has particular string values. SP-1, SP-2, SP-3,.. SP-8
and also V-4 and V-8. I want to add numbers present in the string. The string will be same (either SP- or V-). The numbers following the string will be different. The sum should be separate for each string type.

I have seen many solutions but not able to adapt them.

The table may contain empty cells. Hence I am unable to use Value function.

I want to check the entire table for all SP- strings and V- strings and have the sum of each type. I want to achieve this using formula and not macros. Can any of you help me with the formula

Comment: the table that I am referring is 31*12 size (basically calendar).Having an additional column is last option. I can of course use sumif when this additional column is added for each of existing column. 

I used below formula. But value is resulting in #Value error because of empty cells from VALUE function.{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(AJ10,$E$19:E30)),VALUE(RIGHT(E19:E30,FIND(AJ10,E19:E30)-1)),0)). }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6,C1&"-",""),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. This helped in a quick go.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function SpecialAdder(rng As Range, p As String) As Variant
    Dim L As Long, r As Range
    If p = "" Then
        SpecialAdder = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
        Exit Function
    End If

    SpecialAdder = 0
    L = Len(p)
    For Each r In rng
        If Left(r.Value, L) = p Then
            SpecialAdder = SpecialAdder + Mid(r.Value, L + 1)
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

It would be used in the worksheet like:

```
=specialadder(A1:A100,"SP-")
```

[image]